# How to split string with special character (�) using PHP

Tags: php

Currently I am trying to split the � the special character which represents `%A0` at the URL. However when I use another URL, it doesn't recognize `%A0` therefore I need to use `%20` which is the standard space.

My question is. Is there a way to `explode()` special character �? Whenever I try to explode, it always return a single index array with length 1 array.

```
  //Tried str_replace() to replace %A0 to empty string. Didn't work
  $a = str_replace("%A0"," ", $_GET['view']);

  // Tried to explode() but still returning single element
  $b = explode("�", $a);

  // Returning Array[0] => "Hello World" insteand of 
  // Array[2] => [0] => "Hello", [1] => "World"
  echo $b[0];
```

Comment: See here https://3v4l.org/0o1XJ it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [mb_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php):

```
array mb_split ( string $pattern , string $string [, int $limit = -1 ] )
```

> Split a multibyte string using regular expression pattern and returns
>   the result as an array.

Like this:

```
$string = "a�b�k�e";
$chunks = mb_split("�", $string);
print_r($chunks);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => k
    [3] => e
)
```